# VB.net parse XML nodes <value>

Tags: xml, vb.net

I've found lot of topics showing different ways to parse XML files but it doesn't do what I want. Indeed, I have multiple  nodes that I need to parse in order to get the data betwee:

```
<data_results data_size="64">
  <data>
    <row>
      <value>192.168.53.11|</value>
      <value>22951.2138889</value>
    </row>
    <row>
      <value>192.168.99.100|</value>
      <value>22749.0361111</value>
    </row>
  </data>
</data_results>
```

The purpose is to get back each IP address with the corresponding number of bytes/s and put them in a new row into a table.

But how can I get these info from the XML doc ?

Thanks for your support.

Cheers.

Comment: i have made a nice tutorial on each probabilities look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078780/how-to-select-xmlelements-xmlnodes-xmlattributes-of-specified-values-on-c-sharp

Comment: Indeed it's a good tuto but it doesn't address my case where I've got two child nodes "value" into the same parent node (row).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Dim xml As XDOcument = XDocument.Parse(xmlString)
Dim listRows As List<XElement> = xml.Descendants("row").ToList()

For Each node As XElement in listRows
        Dim values As List<XElement> = node.Descendants("value").ToList()
        // first value is the IP
        Dim ip As String = values(0)
        // second value is the bytes
        Dim bytes As String = values(1)
Next
```

Tried to convert C# code to VB,maybe one or two syntax errors there.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer but I've finally find a way to proceed on my own. Anywa,y your approach is interesting and should worked ;)

Comment: XDocuemnt and XMLDocument is different Xdocuemnt is on .net < 3.5

Comment: @K3rnel31 XDocument is used when you want to perform Linq querys on a Xml document.
Didn't undertand your comment,XDocument exists on .NET > 3.5

Comment: @JotaWA my comment means that `XDcoument` is on versions `3.5,4.0,4.5` but `xmldocument` class is on versions `2.0,3.0`

Comment: Oh,ok,sorry,didn't get it the first time :)

Answer (score 0):

I've finally manage to get my own solution :

```
' Look for the tag "row" into the XML doc
Dim items4 = doc4.GetElementsByTagName("row")
Dim items5 = doc4.GetElementsByTagName("value")

    ' Parse all the XML tag with "row" and get the value for each expected attributes
    For Each item4 As System.Xml.XmlElement In items4

    ounter1 = 0

    For Each item5 As System.Xml.XmlElement In items5

        ' If it's the first value tag then it's the host IP address
        If counter1 = 0 Then

            ' Get the host IP address
            host = item4.ChildNodes(0).InnerText
            Console.WriteLine("host : " & host)

        ' If it's the second value tag then it's the number of Bytes/s
        ElseIf counter1 = 1 Then

            ' Get the host IP address
            bytesPerSec = item4.ChildNodes(1).InnerText
            Console.WriteLine("bytesPerSec : " & bytesPerSec)

        ' Otherwise it's an error
        Else

            ' Do nothing

        End If

            ' Increment counter
            counter1 = counter1 + 1

    Next

' Load the data into the target table
DataGridView10.Rows.Add(New String() {host, bytesPerSec})
```